# How can replace any alphabetic characters (with or without accent) that precede underscore?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I replace any alphabetic characters (with or without accent) that precede underscore ONLY if the character is alone ? Please replace Desired result by JS code.

```
var str = "c_est son avis ";  
//Desired result:
str = "c'est son avis ";  

var str = "cc_est son avis ";  
//Desired result:
str = "cc_est son avis ";  

var str = "Je pense que c_est son avis ";  
//Desired result:
str = "Je pense que c'est son avis ";  

var str = "Je pense que cc_est son avis ";  
//Desired result:
str = "Je pense que cc_est son avis ";
```

Thanks,

Comment: try regex101.com , they will generate a simple replacing code. Try this regex https://regex101.com/r/rH6bZ3/1

Comment: Sounds like you need a word boundary, a letter matching character class and `_`. Set a capturing group around the letter pattern and replace with the backreference to the group + apostrophe.

Comment: @ImmortalDude Thanks for regex sample but  "cc_est son avis " change to the bad result "cc'est son avis ".

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, what is JS REGEX code of your answer ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple use of a regex expression replace would be this:
`str.replace(/(\b\w)\_/g,"$1'")`

It matches at the **beggining of the word** (`\b`) if there is **one letter**(`\w`) and an **underscore**(`\_`), and then replaces with **capture group 1**(`(\b\w)` is `$1` in replace string) and the apostrophe.

You need the **capture group** to keep part of the matched pattern (suppose `c_est` should be kept as `c'est`, you need to keep `c`, which would otherwise be changed with the rest of the regex).

Works on all the above cases.

Answer (score 0):

Probably best using regex (I suck at that) 
But a hacky JS way of doing it would be something like.

```
var x = str.split('_');

for ( var i=0 ; i<x.length ; i++ ){
  if (x[i].length == 1){
  x[i] = x[i]+"'";
  } else if (i < x.length-1){ 
  console.log( i);

  x[i] = x[i] + "_"
  }

}

var y = x.toString()
```

y will be the formatted result

-Edit- fixed the bug as highlighted in the comments.

Comment: Thanks it works., just think to replace "," by "" after array conversion var y = x.toString().

Answer (score 0):

Did you try any code?

You can use indexOF to get the char position of _ and space

```
var n = str.indexOf("_");
var x = str.indexOf(" ");
```